# jQuery - regexp selecting and removeClass()?

Tags: jquery, regex

I've been given several auto-generated HTML docs that are thousands of lines long, and I need to clean up the source. Mostly need to remove classnames like "table-col-##". This is a two-step problem:

1. Select any and all classes that have table-col-##, where ## is an integer between 0-999
2. Remove the matching class from the element, without removing any of the other classes

So it boils down to: I need a way, if possible, to use regexps in $() selectors, and then either to obtain the selected class in each() - or apply the regexp to $.removeClass(). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**: Is there any sort of $.removeClass([selected]) functionality? That seems like the easiest way to solve the second part.

Comment: Would `"[class^='table-col-']"` be acceptable or is that too general?

Comment: Unfortunately too general - there's classes like table-col-new and table-col-bold that need to be preserved.

Comment: after you found items with selector @Jakub Michálek suggested, you can do .each(function(el) { el.className = el.className.replace(/table-col-\d{1,3}/, ""); })

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If only numbers are acceptable, but there can be other characters too, I would start with something like this (not tested, but edited with help from comments):

```
$("[class^='table-col-']").removeClass( function() { /* Matches even table-col-row */
     var toReturn = '',
         classes = this.className.split(' ');
     for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ ) {
         if( /table-col-\d{1,3}/.test( classes[i] ) ) { /* Filters */
             toReturn += classes[i] +' ';
         }
     }
     return toReturn ; /* Returns all classes to be removed */
});
```

Comment: The callback's code can be simplified to `return this.className.split(' ').filter(function(className) {return className.match(/table-col-\d{1,3}/)}).join(' ');`. See [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5ATD/9/).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without the need to split the class names into an array. Let the regular expression do all the work.

For each element found, remove all the classes that match the regular expression.

```js
$("[class^='table-col-']").removeClass( function() {
    return (this.className.match(/\b(table-col-\d{1,3})\b/g) || []).join(' ');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try this out:

**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/AmK4a/1/**

JS:-

```
$(function () {
    $("div").filter(function() {
        return this.className.match(/table-col-\d{0,3}/);
    }).each(function(){
        var classToRemove=this.className.match(/table-col-\d{0,2}/)[0];
        $(this).removeClass(classToRemove);
    });
});
```

Sample HTML:-

```
<div class="table-col-0 temp">Test0</div>
<div class="table-col-99">Test99</div>
<div class="table-col-999">Test999</div>
```

Output HTML:-

```
<div class="temp">Test0</div>
<div class="">Test99</div>
<div class="table-col-999">Test999</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.fn.removeClassRegExp = function (regexp) {
    if(regexp && (typeof regexp==='string' || typeof regexp==='object')) {
        regexp = typeof regexp === 'string' ? regexp = new RegExp(regexp) : regexp;
        $(this).each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass(function(i,c) { 
                var classes = [];
                $.each(c.split(' '), function(i,c) {
                    if(regexp.test(c)) { classes.push(c); }
                });
                return classes.join(' ');
            });
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3D6P/

Comment: this logic stands out of crowd is because it calls `removeClass` only one time, rather than calling in `each` deep well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var className = 'table-col-';
$('[class^='+className+']').removeClass(function(index, class) {
    return class.indexOf(className) == 0;
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

**edited:**

```
var className = 'table-col-';
$('[class^='+className+']').removeClass(function(index, c) {
    var elem = $(this);
    $(c.split(' ')).each(function() {
        var c = this.trim();
        if(this.indexOf(className)==0) {
            elem.removeClass(c);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Much better than my rubbish impl. +1

Comment: Nice. But maybe it's better to avoid reserved words like "class"

Answer (score 0):

This question is now old, but if anybody else comes across it...

I created a simple plugin [jquery.classMatch](https://github.com/ronen/jquery.classMatch) which provides

```
$(selector).hasClassMatch(regexp)
$(selector).removeClassMatch(regexp)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is searching for an alternative regex-based solution:

```
const classes = $(selector).attr('class');
const newClasses = classes.replace(regex, yourNewClass[or part]);
$(selector).removeClass().attr('class', newClasses);
```

I hope this proves helpful.
In my scenario, I utilize this method to locate a class and substitute the attached number:

```
const target = 2;
const bodyClasses = $body.attr('class');
const newBodyClasses  = bodyClasses .replace(/page-\d/, `s${target}`);
$body.removeClass().attr('class', newBodyClasses  );
```